# Adding a compass to camera

Tags: android, camera, compass-geolocation

I need to do the following: The application makes photos and share them on facebook and twitter, the application must have a ruler with compass... like in this application:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sourcebt.android.cameracompass&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zb3VyY2VidC5hbmRyb2lkLmNhbWVyYWNvbXBhc3MiXQ..

The problem is that I have no idea how to make a compass ruler ... If anyone have this problem or know how to implement it, please help me.

Thanks, Charlie.

Comment: Is your problem create the ruler or determining the angle?

Comment: Both.Create the ruler and determining the angle when the phone is rotating.For example, if fallen upon the north, it should show 0 degrees south - 180 degrees, etc.

Comment: I have made a simple round compass and i know how determine the angle ans show correct degrees but i don't know how i can do this in a ruler...How i can draw this ruler? How it will be rotating?

Comment: Do you have an example how to do this?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this, I just wanted you to be clear so that someone with an idea can help you out.